# Is True (In PHP)?

Tags: php, types, compare, boolean

What to use better?

```
if ( $boolean ) {}
```

...or:

```
if ( $boolean === true ) {}
```

Both work, both check that *$boolean* is set to 'true'. The second one also checks *$boolean*'s type.

If we assume that *$boolean* holds value that's boolean, what option should I use?

Comment: Most of time there is no answer to `"What to use better?"` question. Flagged it as a subjective (and pointless, in my opinion)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I disagree, this answer would have helped me.

Comment: @puk you are wrong. if you think it "helped" you - you are doing something wrong

Comment: I'm a newbie to PHP and I am trying to get a better grasp on how to return values from PHP to javascript. I was merely looking for whether PHP should return `true` or `'true'` back to javascript.

Comment: You can only "return" (print-out) strings... but that's other story. `'true'/'false'`

Comment: `Both work, both check that $boolean is set to 'true'.` wrong

Comment: Okay... both checks that after type conversion to boolean variable is `true`. Happy? :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first is better if you simply want a truthy-check.

- It's shorter and thus easier to read
- Even though it doesn't explicitly state equality to true, it's rather obvious what it does

The explicit type check with === is a better choice when you must be sure of the type of the data (eg. input validation or such)

Answer (score 1):

Using `if ( $boolean === true ) {}` when you know that `$boolean` is a boolean is redundant, therefore I wouldn't consider it good practice. This can be further reinforced by naming variables with names that show their *booleaness*, e.g. `$isCool`.

Answer (score 1):

The two, doesn't really do the same thing. `if ($boolean)` is more of a 'not false' statement, asserting true for anything not `false`, `0`, or `null`. If you set `$boolean = 'false'`, the statement will be true.

Assuming that it is a pure boolean comparison you want, you should use the latter case explicity checking that the contents of the variable is in fact a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If `$boolean` is a boolean value, then `if ($boolean)` is fine.

Usually, you only need to do extra checking if you are testing the results of a function, such as `strpos()` that return either a numeric *or* boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

If `$boolean` contains a boolean value *(i.e. `true` or `false`)*, then both proposals will do the same -- the second one being redondant.

If booleans contains a *truthy* or *falsy* value, which is not a boolean, then your second condition will be evaluated to false.

Which one should you use ?

Well, it all depends on what you want to achieve ;-)

- Typically, if any not-`0` number should be considered as true, then, you should use the first syntax
- But if you only want `true` to be considered as truthy, then, you should use the second syntax.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a proper variable name, the first option increases readability, like:

```
if($notValid) {}
```